# R histogram add label with percentage instead of rough values

Tags: r, histogram

I want to use `hist()` to make a histogram using percentages.

However, I also want to place a label at the top of each histogram bar showing the actual percentage.

Here is my code and a link to the output:

```
DataToPlot <- sapply(dataframe, as.numeric)

hist(DataToPlot, xlab="dataframe",ylab="Calls", main="Weekly data", col="lightgreen",labels = TRUE, ylim=c(0, 12000))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `freq = FALSE` option. @jkd got it the wrong way round.
Note the doc says

> `freq` : logical; if TRUE, the histogram graphic is a representation of frequencies, the counts component of the result; if FALSE, probability densities, component density, are plotted (so that the histogram has a total area of one). Defaults to TRUE if and only if breaks are equidistant (and probability is not specified).

If you only want to use base graphics, this is as good as you're going to get with just the `hist()` function. You can add the percentage values manually like so

```
data(iris)

# store the histogram in 'h'
h <- hist(iris$Sepal.Length, xlab="dataframe", ylab="Calls", freq = FALSE, 
          main="Weekly data", col="lightgreen", labels = FALSE, ylim = c(0,0.5))


text(
     x = (h$breaks[-1] + h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)])/2, # compute break center
     y = h$density, # use density as y value
     labels = paste(round((h$density/sum(h$density))*100, 2), "%"), # labels are (density/sum(density)) *100 for %
     pos = 3) # pos = 3 means above the specified coordinates
```

This yields 
[image]

Note that the data I used is from the `iris` dataset since you didn't give any

Comment: No trouble. Just note that the percentage values are *not* the density values times 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `freq = TRUE` option:

```
hist(DataToPlot, xlab="dataframe",ylab="Calls", main="Weekly data", col="lightgreen",labels = TRUE, ylim=c(0, 12000), freq = TRUE)
```

Comment: well, I got exactly the same output

Answer (score 1):

Add this line (`value` is the column you would like to have as lables):

```
labs <- paste(round(DataToPlot$value), "%", sep="")
```

And call the plot like this:

```
hist(DataToPlot, xlab="dataframe",ylab="Calls", main="Weekly data", col="lightgreen",labels = labs, ylim=c(0, 12000))
```

Comment: got an error: 

```Error in DataToPlot$value : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors```